# Play() assets vs. entity in aframe

Tags: javascript, audio, aframe, webvr

I'm able to .play() assets, but not entities in the following structure:

```
 <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
        <audio id="assetNarration" src="snd/dt_narration_1.mp3" preload="auto" autoplay="false">
        <video id="video" src="video/Open_Sky.mp4" autoplay="false" loop></video>
    </a-assets>
        <a-sound id="entityNarration" src="#assetNarration" autoplay="false" position="0 5 0" volume="0.5"></a-sound>
        <a-videosphere id="v1" src="#video" autoplay="false" rotation="0 90 0"></a-videosphere>
 </a-scene>
```

This allows me to trigger:

```
var nar = document.querySelector('#assetNarration');
var vid = document.querySelector('#video');
nar.play();
vid.play();
```

..but not

```
var nar = document.querySelector('#entityNarration');
var vid = document.querySelector('#v1');
nar.play();
vid.play();
```

The major difference with this is that I'm setting volume and position values on the entity, which are ignored if I trigger .play() directly on the asset.

Comment: Typo I guess, asssetNarration  with double ss?

Comment: Thanks @VuralAcar, but I re-typed code here in SO for simplification purposes.  My actual code is using other variables.  But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try `el.components.sound.playSound()`. Else, try passing an inline URL directly since it creates an audio buffer which is a bit more flexible.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: nar.playSound is not a function`
Passing an inline URL directly skips preloading the file, correct?  My actual code is heavily relying on <a-assets> in order to preload everything before running the rest of the code.
BTW, I'm editing my post to show this, but the question goes beyond just audio. I can't seem to trigger any action on entities... video or sound.

Comment: Sorry, updated for `el.components.sound.playSound()`. You can try using `<a-asset-item src="youraudio.mp3">` to preload within three.js system.

Comment: crazy fact: if you `.play()` an asset, it will play in stereo, if you `components.sound.playSound()` an entity, it will play mono.

Comment: It's positionally tracked audio, so it might play more in one ear depending on the audio locally. I am not sure how accurate the positional audio is right now though.

Comment: Yea I've been able to play with the positioning, but this is different.  Literally mute on left and audio on right.  If I move the position around there will be a difference in the spatial levels, but it is odd that with a `position="0 0 0"` its all to the right.